# Python - can't define set of user-defined objects

Tags: python, set

I am getting the following error

```
    all_rots = set([rot1, rot2])
TypeError: an integer is required
```

My code is simply

```
rot1 = SimpleClass(mapping={1:1, 2:2})
rot2 = SimpleClass(mapping={2:2, 1:1})
all_rots = set([rot1, rot2])
```

(this is in unit test)

And the SimpleClass class is

```
class SimpleClass(object):
    def __init__(self, mapping):
        self._mapping = mapping


    @property
    def mapping(self):
        return self._mapping


    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.mapping[key]

    def __hash__(self):
        return sorted(list(self.mapping.iteritems()))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if type(other) is type(self):
            return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
        return False
```

Anyone has any idea why I cannot construct set of my objects?

Comment: `__hash__` should return an integer not a list.

Comment: As an aside, `list(self.mapping.iteritems()` is equivalent to `self.mapping.items()`

Comment: I see. Any ideas how to fix it? I am basically trying to hash dictionaries, my class is a wrapper for a dictionary. How is that done correctly?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga in python 2 only. But `__hash__` should return an int anyway.

Comment: So what's the best way to fix my approach then? I.e. how do I get a hashable dict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__hash__` should return an integer not a list.

You can create an immutable/hashable type from your sorted list (e.g. tuple) and return the hash of that:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(tuple(sorted(self.mapping.items())))
```

---

```
rot1 = SimpleClass(mapping={1:1, 2:2})
rot2 = SimpleClass(mapping={2:2, 1:1})
all_rots = set([rot1, rot2])
print all_rots
# set([<Rotation object at 0x7f737e5ef210>])
```

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds :) `sorted` would work better with `items()` (no need to rebuild the list for python 2, and also works in python 3)